# WordPress - pagination on template page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building my site with WordPress templates for granular control over how each of them looks.

I have my loop on my news page to pull in posts from, well, posts.

Working fine, or so I thought.

```
<?php 
/*
    Template Name: News
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main-content">

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php query_posts ("posts_per_page=4"); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <div class="entry">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>
    <div class="postmetadata">
        <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
        Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | 
        <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
    </div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<div class="navigation">
<div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>

</div> <!-- end div main-content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The older/newer entries show up, but after clicking on them it just takes me to the same page/newest 4 posts.

How do I get the pagination working with template pages like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `paged` parameter to `query_posts()` to paginate the results:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged); 
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="navigation">
<div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
```

Just put this line in your page.